# C++ search for a node in an ordered linked list

Tags: c++, list, search

Hi I have an ordered linked list using structs. The struct has two elements: string name and int id.  I am trying to search for a specific node so I can then print it but I keep getting the "Core Dump (Segmentation fault)" error when I try to run the code.

```
/*
 * search: Auxiliary function that searches for a specific node in the list.
 */
node* search(node* head, int c){  
    node* aux = head; 
    
    while (aux != NULL && aux->id != c)  
        aux = aux->next;  
    return aux;  
}  

/* 
 * showNode: Prints the information of a specific node (search is done by ID).
 */ 
void showNode(node* head, int c) {
    node* aux = head;
    node* resp;

    if (aux != NULL) {
        resp = search(aux, c);
        if(resp->id == c)
            print(resp);
        else
            printf("Node wasn't found");
    } else {
        printf("Error: Empty list. \n");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if `resp == nullptr`?

Comment: `if (resp != null && resp->id == c)` or such. and `aux->id > c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see one problem straight away (though there may be others).

Your `search` function will return `NULL` if the item cannot be found, yet you blindly go and check if `resp->id == c` - that's unlikely to end well.

You can fix that reasonably easily, you just have to adjust your check in `showNode()`:

```
// Find a node and return it, or nullptr if not found.

node *search(node *curr, int c) {  
    while (curr != nullptr && curr->id < c)  
        curr = curr->next;
    return (curr != nullptr && curr->id == c) ? curr : nullptr;  
} 

// Find a node and print it (or if it couldn't be found).
void showNode(node *head, int c) {
    node *resp = search(head, c);
    if (resp != nullptr) {
        print(resp);
    } else {
        printf("Node wasn't found");
    }
}
```

You'll see I've made some other changes as well, the complete list is:

- Using the more modern `nullptr` rather than `NULL`;
- Removing `aux` in `search()`, as the parameter passed in is a copy anyway: you may as well just use that (renamed to `curr` since it's technically doesn't stay the head any more);
- Dropping out of the search as soon as we find an element greater than or equal to what we want (since, as you state, it's ordered, and I'm *assuming* order is ascending - if we're looking for `7` and get to `42`, there's no chance `7` will exist beyond that). Then we just return it if it's equal, or return `nullptr` if not;
- Removing the possibility of trying to dereference a `nullptr`;
- Not distinguishing between an item not found in an empty list, and an item not found in a non-empty list (something of dubious value). This allows simplification of the `showNode()` code.